# Toggle class between fixed-bottom and position-sticky

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the footer to have class position-sticky but toggled to fixed-bottom when it reached the bottom of the page.

Here is what i have so far.

```js
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
        var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
        var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
        if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
            $('#bottom-fix').addClass('position-sticky').removeClass('fixed-bottom');
        }
        else {
            $('#bottom-fix').removeClass('position-sticky').addClass('fixed-bottom');
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="py-md-3 py-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-justify">
                <p>Welcome, folks… welcome to Kitty Bingo, the online bingo site where treats are on the loose! Claim your share of the freebies, the Welcome Bonus, by registering via any devices. 300% bingo bonus and 100 FREE Spins are up for grabs on your first deposit. Seize the occasion whenever you want, furry friends! </p>
                <p>How can you claim the offer? It’s simple. You need to deposit at least £10 to be eligible. Select the offer in the cashier and you’re done! The fresh bucks in your account seep in along with 300% the deposit amount as a bonus. Does that mean Kitty Bingo is tripling your credits to play? Exactly! You can enjoy up to a maximum bonus of £150!</p>
                <p>The funds are credited instantly. And you may browse through the list of online slots or bingo rooms to put those bonuses to play! Visit the many 75-ball bingo, 90-ball bingo and 5-line bingo rooms. They feature varying ticket prices, gameplays and significantly, Progressive Jackpots. Each time a wager is set, it contributes to the pot that grows in size! </p>
                <p>And what about those 100 Free Spins? Get them in batches of 20 Free Spins for 5 consecutive days. A way to let the fun last longer! Free Spins are playable on a range of selected games from the Exclusive Games Collection. Find popular titles including Jazz Cat Slot, Gladiator Gold, Blackbeard Booty Slot and The Lost Slot Of Riches.</p>
                <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
               <p>At Kitty Bingo, the fun knows no bounds! Drop by the Promotions Page whenever you want to refill your bonus balance. The Welcome Package issues second deposit bonuses as well. If you’re in the mood to double your deposit with 100% Bingo Bonus or claim 50% Slots Bonus, do not hesitate to deposit a second time. A third deposit leads to a 150% Bingo Bonus or 75% Slot Bonus at Kitty Bingo!</p>
                <p>What’s left to do? Click on the Join Now and be part of the cat-loving bingo site, Kitty Bingo!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom" id="bottom-fix" style="background-color: #08A8E4;">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-kitty d-inline-block">JOIN NOW</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

There is some kind of flickering when reached the bottom.
Any help ?

Comment: why can't it just be fixed all the time? I believe position sticky and fixed are essentially the same thing... the flicker is caused by the toggle between the classes.

Comment: You many not need  either of them. Could you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @TJWeems if it's fixed all the time, the button will cover part of the text on the footer

Comment: @mahan I want the join now button to stick to the bottom when it reached there. In Bootstrap 4 the class used should allow use to see the footer text clearly

Answer (score 0):

change the if condition with this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
```

Comment: Not working for me. Can you please make a codepen with Bootstrap 4